# Socket Programming - How to connect a remote address

Tags: python, sockets

I am practicing socket programming using python. I am fimiliar with how to make a simple tcp server and client in local address but I want to know how to make it possible so that I can connect to my own computer from a client app that I built. What modifications do I have to make in this server script? or client?

> server:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#The host is set to be the local machine.
address = ("127.0.0.1",1234)

s.bind(address)

s.listen(1)

c , addr = s.accept()

while True:
    #do some stuff
c.close()
```

> client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

address = ("127.0.0.1",1234)

s.connect(address)

while True:
    #Do client stuff
s.close()
```

Comment: Basically I want to make my own computer a running server.

Comment: If you are directly connected to the internet you don't have to change anything. If you are connecting through a firewall/router you may need to forward/open ports. What is your network setup?

Comment: The code would not execute. Post a [mcve] to more likely get helped.

Comment: @syntonym What do you mean by network setup?

Comment: How is your computer connected to the internet? And where do you expect will your client sit?

Comment: via Wi-fi. I have a simple server script that acts as a calculator. What I want to practise is that, I will keep the server script running on my computer and I will connect it via another device on another network using my client app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not allowed to make comments yet. But if you have a client app on another device, you can make the HOST your machines IP that stores the server. IF you're using windows ENTER: ipconfig    In your command line argument. I think that or Linux its if config. You should be able to set your address to your machines ip address in order to get the client to connect to your local machine. As you noted, localhost will not work.

Comment: Should I change the host in both client and server scripts or in server it is okay to make it local machine since the local machine will be the server. In client script, I will change the host to the ip address of my server machine?

Comment: I am working on a similar application (A client on an android that needs to connect to a server on my local machine). I haven’t lunched it, but from my research it appears as if you would set both the client and the server to the local machine IP. However, I believe that it could work if you only change the client script to the machines IP, and you may be able to keep the server script set to localhost. I would try both methods. If I finish my program before you, I will update you on which method works. I assume both can work.